# Pyplot saving blank figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to save graphics in very high quality, like eps. Basically I need to save 4 images of a hyperspectral data. Showing the graphics is not a problem, so I know my figures are ok, but I can't save them.

I have already tried other formats, like jpg,png or pdf, and none of them worked. I also already tried to save 4 figures instead of one figure with 4 subplots, but the problem persisted. I changed also matplotlib's backend a lot of times, and none of them worked.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

RGB = np.random.randint(255, size=(3518,117,3))
var = RGB[:,:,0] 
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('cividis')        
col = 3   
forma = "eps"
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,col,figsize = (1.5,45))

plt.subplots_adjust(left = 2, right = 4)

im = ax[0].imshow(RGB.astype(np.uint8), cmap = cmap)       

ax[1].pcolormesh(var, cmap = cmap)

ax[2].plot(np.mean(var,axis = 1),np.arange(var.shape[0]))

plt.colorbar(im)
fig.savefig("runnable" + "." + forma, format = forma,dpi=1200 )

plt.show()
```

I get a warning that I don't understand:

> RunTimeWarning:"Mean of empty slice"

I've done some research and it seems like this is common when there is `NaN` in the data. However, I looked for it and didn't find any.

edit: I changed the code so it can be runnable.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help here without [mcve].

Comment: try `plt.savefig()`

Comment: @JakeP `plt.savefig` is the same as `plt.gcf().savefig`, which is the same as `fig.savefig` in this case.